# Change the system volume using Android Car Audio Manager

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to change the system volume in an Android app running on A14.
Below is my code, but I'm facing a compilation error:

```
// Using CarAudioManager to change the volume
Car car = Car.createCar(context);
this.mCarAudioManager = (CarAudioManager) car.getCarManager(Car.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(this.mCarAudioManager != null) {
    int zoneId = PRIMARY_AUDIO_ZONE;
    final int flags = 1; // To show the UI
    int index = volumeToSet;
    int groupId = 0;
    this.mCarAudioManager.setGroupVolume(zoneId, groupId, index, flags);       
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "CarAudioManager is null");
}
```

And this is the error itself. Why can't setGroupVolume be found?

> /data/home/sarao/alexa_workspace/repo_workspace/base_s/Alexa_Auto_App/aacs/android/app-components/alexa-auto-media-player/src/main/java/com/amazon/alexa/auto/media/MusicStreamAttributeUpdater.java:103:
> error: cannot find symbol
> this.mCarAudioManager.setGroupVolume(zoneId, groupId, index, flags);
> ^   symbol:   method setGroupVolume(int,int,int,int)

In the Gradle file, I have imported the library
`useLibrary 'android.car'`

These are the Java imports used:

```
// Change volume
import android.car.Car;
import android.car.media.CarAudioManager;
import android.content.Context;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```

Answer (score 0):

This method has `@SystemApi` annotation meaning it's hidden for public developers. You can't use it

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/car-lib/src/android/car/media/CarAudioManager.java#470